# rpcgen adds _svc extension

Tags: c, linux, rpc

Creating a simple `server-client` program using `rpcgen`.

I'm writing this `.x` file:

```
program REMOTE_PROG {
    version MSG_RCV {
        int STRLEN(string)      = 1;
        double SQUARE(double *) = 2;
        int NUM_OF_DEV(int *)   = 3;

    } = 1;
} = 99;
```

executing with `rpcgen file.x` -> generates `file_svc.c`.

in the  `file_svc.c` file, for some reason, it generates each function case with `_svc` extension:

```
case STRLEN:
    xdr_argument = xdr_wrapstring;
    xdr_result = xdr_int;
    local = (char *(*)()) strlen_1_svc; //<--_SVC
    break;
```

and when I try to compile the server after implementing the functions

```
int * strlen_1(char **, CLIENT *);
```

the compiler raises that error:

```
"_strlen_1_svc", referenced from:
  _remote_prog_1 in file_svc-8501b7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

But if I'll delete that auto generated _svc extension,`local = (char *(*)()) strlen_1; //no _svc` the program will compile successfully.
**Why does this happen? why does the rpcgen adds the _svc extension to the functions and am I doing something wrong when I delete the _svc?**

P.S same error also for square and num_of_dev functions, gave only strlen for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the convention, the _svc is short for service.

Your server needs to implement the service function, that is the `strlen_1_svc` function.

Your client calls the `strlen_1` function. rpcgen + the RPC library does all the inbetween - it generates code for `strlen_1` used by the client which will serialize the data and transfer it to the server, where an event loop dispatches the call to your code in the `strlen_1_svc` function.

Comment: thanks, got it! (accidently deleted comment:
  so I need to implement the `int * strlen_1_svc(char **, struct svc_req *);`
instead of `int * strlen_1(char **, CLIENT *);` ?)

Answer (score 0):

After execution of `rpcgen ex7.x` you should have created the client and server stubs `ex7_clnt.c` and `ex7_svc.c` and also a header file `ex7.h`

In the header file you will have declared both functions `strlen_1` and `strlen_1_svc`, they have to have different names as they are different functions: first one is on the client side and invokes the second one on the server side through RPC call.